# Internal logic of locally strongly finitely presentable categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, locally-presentable-categories, algebraic-theory

There is a duality between [locally strongly finitely presentable (LSFP) categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+strongly+finitely+presentable+category) and (Cauchy complete) cartesian categories, i.e. [multisorted algebraic theories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+theory) [1]. The [internal logic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+logic) of [cartesian categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cartesian+monoidal+category) is well known to be [first-order equational logic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/universal+algebra). What is the internal logic of locally strongly finitely presentable categories? It should at least subsume "exact logic" (i.e. have finite conjunction, existential quantification, and quotients of equivalence relations), since the category of models for any multisorted algebraic theory is [exact](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exact+category). However, it may not be describable as fragment of first-order logic, because although there exist arbitrary disjunctions, conjunction does not distributive over disjunction.

*Edited in 2024.* The original motivation for this question was to better understand the relationship between syntax and semantics. Cartesian categories have a well understood internal logic, but form a duality with a class of categories with (seemingly) much more structure. In theory, these should be described by a different internal language, and the duality between the two classes of categories (cartesian and LSFP) should then express some kind of equi-expressibility result between the respective logics, which could lend syntactic insight into the relationship between the two fragments of logic.

[1] [On the duality between varieties and algebraic theories](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s000120300002), J. Adámek, F.W. Lawvere & J. Rosický.

Comment: @SimonHenry: thanks. I had overlooked the distributivity condition for disjunction.

Comment: Ah yes you are right, I forgot they were always regular, so you do get existential quantification. In fact they are exact categories, so you also get quotient by equivalence relations internally. It is not clear to me you'll get much more than that though: so far I see no other good properties of these categories might not transpire in the internal logic, as a property needs to have some form of pullback stability to have an internal interpretation. But maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: It is going to be Barr exact, via monadicity. I think you can't say more than this.

Comment: Perhaps to get a one-to-one correspondence, one would need to relax the requirement that the logic be a fragment of first-order logic, then?

Comment: A category is locally strongly finitely-presentable iff it is the category of models of a theory in a certain logic (algebraic logic). Maybe the lesson is that being the models of an _external_ theory which is formulated in a certain class of external logic is not typically going to guarantee you have suitable properties for a good _internal_ logic.

Comment: I suppose this is a good lesson, but it seems reasonable to expect that an internal logic _does_ exist, even if it is not as well-behaved as one might like. It still seems plausible that allowing the logic to have some unusual behaviour (e.g. no distributivity of conjunction over disjunction) would still result in a somewhat reasonable logic.

Comment: For one thing, the more expressive the external logic, the more general the categories, so the weaker the corresponding internal logic will be. So if there were a general link between the properties of the external specifying logic and the interpretable internal logic, it would establish some kind of duality between highly expressive and highly restricted logics. I think it would be remarkable to discover such a duality. Sorry if I'm distracting from the specific question at hand!

Comment: The problem is that internal logic (even extended far beyind first order logic) can only talk about pullback stable properties. There is no reason you can arrive at a characterization of some class of categories only by pullback stable properties. However, something encouraging : if $C$ is a category of model of a multisorted algebraic theory, then any slice of $C$ is also a category of model of a multisorted algebraic theory. So that's a starting point...

Comment: In [How algebraic is algebra?](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/8/n9/8-09abs.html) Adamek, Lawvere, and Rosicky systematically study all the "algebraic" categorical properties enjoyed by LSFP categories. I think this encompasses properties like regularity and exactness which are needed to set up internal logic. So Ivan's sense that "you can't say more than that" should be something that can be made precise.

Comment: "I think it would be remarkable to discover such a duality."

I completely agree. But in a sense, it seems like such a relationship is suggested by Gabriel–Ulmer duality, in which the models for one kind of theory produce a theory of the other kind. Perhaps I have misunderstood the significance of this duality.

Comment: @varkor I think Gabriel-Ulmer duality is an instance of the general duality between syntax and semantics: for any given "logical doctrine", there is a duality between the theories of that doctrine ("syntactic" side) and the categories of models in that doctrine (semantic side). The kind of duality I'm talking about would be a duality relating different doctrines to each other.

Comment: @TimCampion: I'm not sure where one would draw the line between syntactic and semantic structure here. E.g. a Grothendieck topos is, in a sense, very close the notion of locally presentable category (i.e. semantic structure). However, it has an internal logic given by geometric theories (i.e. syntactic structure).

Comment: @varkor I agree that the distinction between syntax and semantics is blurred in categorical logic. My larger point was that I don't see the analogy between Gabriel-Ulmer duality and the hypothetical duality I brought up, beyond the fact that they are / would be dualities in categorical logic. For instance, the kind of duality I'm talking about might say things like "full first-order logic is dual to cartesian logic" or "higher-order logic is dual to monoidal logic". It would be way out there.

Comment: I will not comment on the philosophical discussion. On a quantitative level, in the paper "On the abstract characterization of quasi-varieties" by Pedicchio and Vitale, Thm 2.3 recalls that a category is a variety if it is exact and it has an abstractly finite, regular projective, regular generating family. So the internal logic is simply exact, while the properties of the generator simplify the Mitchell-Bénabou language.

Comment: Still, this simplification of the complexity of the Mitchell-Bénabou language has repercussions on the internal logic of the category. For example finite limits will commute with directed one. This happens because the generator interacts directly with the internal logic, given that it is "abstractly finite".

Comment: To finish this discussion, my bet is that the internal logic is "exact" and "sifted colimits commute with products". This reminds me the notion of precontinuity from "Toward a Characterization of Algebraic Exactness" by Adamek and Rosicky.

Comment: As Ivan points out, in the paper I linked to, a full characterization of the algebraic properties is not completely achieved. Ivan mentions [this follow-on](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2003.06.009) which does obtain a form of characterization. One thing worth mentioning which they show is that in an algebraic category, regular epis, while not necessarily pullback-stable, are finite-product-stable. Maybe something can be done with that in the internal logic.

Comment: A characterisation of algebraically exact categories was achieved by Garner in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.0106.pdf.

Comment: @SimonHenry Hang on -- in an algebraic category, a regular epi is just a morphism which is surjective on all sorts, no? So regular epis _are_ stable under pullback (because surjections are stable under pullback)!

Comment: @TimCampion Yes, but I'm not sure what you are answering too.

Comment: Speaking as a user of category theory who hasn't spent time thinking about the intersection of category theory and logic, I liked the first sentence of this question, but would have liked links to "internal logic," "exact logic," and some motivation for why this question is important, or what research it's related to.

Comment: @DavidWhite: I've added some links for context, and provided a little background on my motivation for asking this question. Tim Campion's answer explains what would be needed for a resolution to this question: i.e. a syntactic interpretation of the structure that characterises algebraically exact categories, but I don't believe anyone has studied all of these properties syntactically so far.

Answer (score 4):

The comments are getting a bit long (sorry, that is largely my fault), so I think it's worth expanding on Jiří Rosický 's point, which comes very close to completely answering the question.

Adamek, Lawvere, and Rosicky introduced the notion of an *algebraically exact category* in [How algebraic is algebra?](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/8/n9/8-09abs.html), giving a precise definition of what it means for a category to have all of the "exactness" properties enjoyed by *(possibly multisorted) varieties* (= algebraic categories = locally strongly finitely-presentable) categories. The definition is conceptually illuminating: the forgetful functor $Var \to Cat$ has a left adjoint, and an algebraically exact category is defined to be a pseudoalgebra for the induced pseudomonad on $Cat$.

They observed that every algebraically exact category $\mathcal C$ has the following properties:

- $\mathcal C$ has limits.
- $\mathcal C$ has sifted colimits.
- $\mathcal C$ is Barr-exact.
- finite limits commute with filtered colimits in $\mathcal C$.
- regular epimorphisms are stable under products in $\mathcal C$.
- filtered colimits distribute over products in $\mathcal C$.\
- (This one must apparently follow from the rest: regular epis are stable under pullback.)

They conjectured that these properties completely characterize the algebraically exact categories. This conjecture was proven under various additional assumptions by these and other authors, until it was finally proven in full generality by Garner in [A characterization of algebraic exactness](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.0106) (see Garner for a full bibliography).

**Upshot:** It would seem the appropriate internal logic would be "whatever you can express using the above properties". In particular, Barr-exactness gives a good fragment of logic. Stability of regular epis under pullback probably lets you do a reasonable amount more. Perhaps others can elaborate on / correct these statements.

**Side note:** I would assume that only the "finitary" fragment of the above properties would be relevant to building an internal logic as it's usually conceived. I would be interested to be proven wrong about that though!

Comment: I'm a bit confused because in his abstract, Garner states the characterization slightly differently than in the body of the paper. He includes the condition that the "take the sifted colimit" functor be continuous, which I thought was equivalent to sifted colimits commuting with all limits, which seems too strong.  Perhaps the point is that limits in $Sind(C)$ are not computed "levelwise" when objects are viewed as diagrams in $C$ indexed by sifted categories?

Comment: Asking for $\mathrm{Sind}(\mathbf C) \to \mathbf C$ to be continuous is equivalent to asking for small limits to *distribute* over sifted colimits. (This is mentioned in *How algebraic is algebra?*.)

Comment: Presumably there's one extra condition on the internal logic for LSFP categories, on top of that for algebraically exact categories, viz. some freeness condition on the sifted colimits, but this seems like a mostly inconsequential detail: if one is interesting in reasoning in a LSFP category, it should be enough to consider it simply as an algebraically exact category.

Comment: @varkor Thanks for clearing up my confusion! Maybe the Barr-exactness and product-stability of regular epis are saying something about freeness. But I agree, the full force of freeness is basically what differentiates algebraic categories from  algebraically-exact ones. I'd say the full force of freeness is a global property of the category, whereas internal logic relies on local properties of objects in the category."

Comment: By analogy, even the internal logic of $Set$ doesn't allow you to express anything with unbounded quantifiers; freeness _as such_ feels like it would need an unbounded quantifier to express (EDIT: and maybe even quantification over "classes"?). Maybe something like Mike Shulman's stack semantics allows to express unbounded quantification?

Comment: That's a good point: I wouldn't expect the freeness property to be expressible syntactically without unbounded quantification. For the purposes of the original question, a characterisation of the internal logic for algebraically complete categories would be completely sufficient.